# Delete last column in dataframe in a while loop

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I'm working on comparing two dataframes, that contains all days within a month. `prediction` and `validation`

```
print(prediction)
day            1         2        3       4        5        6        7   ...           25           26           27           28        29        30      31
balance  1228.939  1140.939  1085.35  885.35  883.373  819.922  813.449  ...  1190.251818  1185.706364  1162.979091  1190.251818  1247.277  1247.277  647.17
```

`validation` however, may contain 28, 30 or 31 days, depending on the month of observation, while `predicition` is static and will always contain 31 days.
This is an example of `validation` where it contains 28 rows.

```
            balance  flag  day  month  year   fdate
date
2019-02-01  2957.23     8    1      2  2019  201902
2019-02-02  2909.23     8    2      2  2019  201902
2019-02-03  2909.23     8    3      2  2019  201902
2019-02-04  2909.23     8    4      2  2019  201902
2019-02-05  2909.23     8    5      2  2019  201902
2019-02-06  2909.23     8    6      2  2019  201902
2019-02-07  2909.23     8    7      2  2019  201902
2019-02-08  2909.23     8    8      2  2019  201902
2019-02-09  2909.23     8    9      2  2019  201902
2019-02-10  2909.23     8   10      2  2019  201902
2019-02-11  2909.23     8   11      2  2019  201902
2019-02-12  2909.23     8   12      2  2019  201902
2019-02-13  2909.23     8   13      2  2019  201902
2019-02-14  2909.23     8   14      2  2019  201902
2019-02-15  2909.23     8   15      2  2019  201902
2019-02-16  2909.23     8   16      2  2019  201902
2019-02-17  2909.23     8   17      2  2019  201902
2019-02-18  2909.23     8   18      2  2019  201902
2019-02-19  2909.23     8   19      2  2019  201902
2019-02-20  3045.50     8   20      2  2019  201902
2019-02-21  3045.50     8   21      2  2019  201902
2019-02-22  3014.98     8   22      2  2019  201902
2019-02-23  3014.98     8   23      2  2019  201902
2019-02-24  3014.98     8   24      2  2019  201902
2019-02-25  3014.98     8   25      2  2019  201902
2019-02-26  3014.98     8   26      2  2019  201902
2019-02-27  3014.98     8   27      2  2019  201902
2019-02-28  3014.98     8   28      2  2019  201902
```

I'm trying to create a while loop, that will drop the last column of `prediction` until the amount of rows for `validation` matches the amount of columns for `prediction`. This way I can transpose `prediction` and append it to `validation` and then I can calculate correlation, or any other goodness of fit measure. 
Is this the correct approach to delete the last column of `prediction` until the condition is met?

```
    while len(prediction.columns) > len(list(validation['balance'])):
         prediction = prediction.drop(prediction.columns[len(prediction.columns)-1], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

And then after concatenating both dataframes the final output would be:

```
            balance  flag  day  month  year   fdate bal_pred
date
2019-02-01  2957.23     8    1      2  2019  201902 1228.939
2019-02-02  2909.23     8    2      2  2019  201902 1140.939
2019-02-03  2909.23     8    3      2  2019  201902 1085.35
2019-02-04  2909.23     8    4      2  2019  201902 885.35
2019-02-05  2909.23     8    5      2  2019  201902 883.373
2019-02-06  2909.23     8    6      2  2019  201902 819.922
2019-02-07  2909.23     8    7      2  2019  201902 813.449
2019-02-08  2909.23     8    8      2  2019  201902 ... 
2019-02-09  2909.23     8    9      2  2019  201902 ... 
2019-02-10  2909.23     8   10      2  2019  201902 ...
2019-02-11  2909.23     8   11      2  2019  201902 ...
2019-02-12  2909.23     8   12      2  2019  201902 ...
2019-02-13  2909.23     8   13      2  2019  201902 ...
2019-02-14  2909.23     8   14      2  2019  201902 ...
2019-02-15  2909.23     8   15      2  2019  201902 ...
2019-02-16  2909.23     8   16      2  2019  201902 ...
2019-02-17  2909.23     8   17      2  2019  201902 ...
2019-02-18  2909.23     8   18      2  2019  201902 ...
2019-02-19  2909.23     8   19      2  2019  201902 ...
2019-02-20  3045.50     8   20      2  2019  201902 ...
2019-02-21  3045.50     8   21      2  2019  201902 ...
2019-02-22  3014.98     8   22      2  2019  201902 ...
2019-02-23  3014.98     8   23      2  2019  201902 ...
2019-02-24  3014.98     8   24      2  2019  201902 ...
2019-02-25  3014.98     8   25      2  2019  201902 1190.25
2019-02-26  3014.98     8   26      2  2019  201902 1185.71
2019-02-27  3014.98     8   27      2  2019  201902 1162.98
2019-02-28  3014.98     8   28      2  2019  201902 1190.25
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
prediction=prediction.T.iloc[0:len(validation)]
```

or in a one step:

```
validation['prediction']=prediction.T.iloc[0:len(validation)]['balance']
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. The one step didn't work dircetly, I ended up creating a new dataframe off the transpose and then joining it.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do this in pandas is:

```
prediction = prediction.iloc[:, :len(validation)]
```